# What is the process to change your articles of association for a business in Estonia?

Tags: business, estonia

What is the procedure to follow for amending the Articles of Association for a business entity registered in Estonia?

I'm looking to register a business in Estonia. One of the prerequisites is to write the company's Articles of Association.

I know that many companies' Articles of Incorporation are short documents that reference external documents (bylaws) because changing the Articles of Association can often be complex, timely, and costly -- but changing the bylaws are much simpler.

Does it cost any money to change the Articles of Association for a company registered in Estonia? How long does it take, and what does that process look like?

Comment: I don't think this has to do with expatriate status, as the legal issues would apply to a citizen of Estonia as well. Take a look at [help/on-topic] to get an idea of what's appropriate here.